# Pad summed results with 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm, rails-postgresql

I have a rails 4 (ruby 2) app that tracks time for employees against various companies. I need to get a sum of the minutes per company per date. My problem is I'm not sure the best way to pad date/company pairs with 0 if there are no time entries for that company on that day.

**Tables**

```
Companies      Time_Entries
id name ...    id, created_at, company_id, minutes ...
```

**Current output** given only 2 companies and 2 days,

```
[{"company_id":1,"company_name":"Company A","date":"2013-06-24","minutes":987},
 {"company_id":1,"company_name":"Company A","date":"2013-06-25","minutes":5},
 {"company_id":2,"company_name":"Company B","date":"2013-06-24","minutes":500}]
```

**Expected output** to do is pad days that aren't recorded with 0's is to have an additional item in the list where the last item is the new item.

```
[{"company_id":1,"company_name":"Company A","date":"2013-06-24","minutes":987},
 {"company_id":1,"company_name":"Company A","date":"2013-06-25","minutes":5},
 {"company_id":2,"company_name":"Company B","date":"2013-06-24","minutes":500},
 {"company_id":2,"company_name":"Company B","date":"2013-06-25","minutes":0}]
```

**Current Query (PostgreSQL)**

```
 @minutes = TimeEntry.where("created_at >= ?", 1.week.ago.utc)
  .group('companies.id, date(created_at)')
  .joins(:company)
  .select("companies.id as company_id", "companies.name as company_name", "date(created_at)", "SUM(minutes) as minutes")
  .order("date ASC")
```

I'm not sure the best way to go about this. I can think of a couple options:

- A 3 deep loop that loops through days, than a loop through companies, than a loop through found results to add any day/company pairs that have not already been added.
- Do a left join on a `generate_series()` for a date range in postgresq and coalesce null sums to 0, but I don't think that will get me all the way
- Some unknown better more elegant option

Comment: Syntax error. please explain your intentions. And what you actually tried. A data model would help, too.

Comment: Fair enough... I've actually refactored my graphing library to not be so picky with the data... So this question is basically a dud now. If I delete the question will you lose your comment upvote?